# Very strange rails error (UnknownHttpMethod: POST) occured during tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My backend has a set of tests (for ruby on rails). These tests were all green at some point of time, but 2 days ago I started to run them (I was not working on website for 1 month), and some of them are red

The error is very strange

Test is

```
post "/login", {:format => :json, :email => email, :password => password}
assert_response status, response.body
```

And error is

```
ActionController::UnknownHttpMethod: POST, accepted HTTP methods are OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, CONNECT, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, MKCOL, COPY, MOVE, LOCK, UNLOCK, VERSION-CONTROL, REPORT, CHECKOUT, CHECKIN, UNCHECKOUT, MKWORKSPACE, UPDATE, LABEL, MERGE, BASELINE-CONTROL, MKACTIVITY, ORDERPATCH, ACL, SEARCH, and PATCH
test/integration/helpers/basic_helpers.rb:7:in `login'
test/integration/integration_users_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:IntegrationUser>'
```

The error is very strange for 2 reasons:

- Obviously, POST should be allowed
- It was 100% working before. I am thinking about some strange change in environment (gems updated???).

What do you think can cause error like this?

Comment: I'm assuming line 7 of basic_helpers.rb is the line starting with `post`? Is there any way you can revert to when it was working "before"? If you're using git, you can checkout a specific commit

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer. I have modified ruby String class.

```
class String

def upcase
  self.mb_chars.upcase
end

end
```

This was quite stupid decision because it breaks functionality =(

Comment: Consider doing [this](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) to your patch if you desperately need it.